# Find bad data which is causing my column become an "object" type instead of integer type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a 40 Million .csv file, I used read_csv() and loaded it into a dataframe. The ID column is interpreted as "object" type. It should be an integer. How to I find out what is causing this ?

The reason could be it has some string like data in my .csv. How do I extract this bad data and see what it is ?

```
Id

1324
1234
1234
....
'bad data'
....
....
'bad data'
....
....
1489
1254
```

Comment: paste the stack trace.

Comment: I am a novice user of pandas and wonder if there are tricks or functions to know more about his 'bad data'

Comment: Use `mask = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce').isna()`. Then, you can do `df['ID'].loc[mask]`. That will filter out only the non-numeric values of your ID column

Comment: That worked!! Thank you